# Error occured when VM initialization while running play frame work project

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, jvm-arguments

Hi all am trying to create play project after creating a project i got a error for JVM

while type `play run myproject` (runs within my project) it shows

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I got some answers from SO for this issue i changed the memory settings for JVM followed by this [link to set memory space for JVM](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7) i added `-Xmx512m` to java but still its showing the same problem.

Comment: This might not be relevant but typically you would start your application by typing `play run` from inside your project directory. You can find more details [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/PlayConsole).

Comment: @mantithetical am running play from my project directory only.

Comment: Using Linux or Windows? If Linux have you recently modified `/etc/security/limits.conf`? Also can you run any other Java program?

Comment: @BahmanM. Am using windows only causing the same problem

Comment: @BahmanM. No am using windows;

Comment: How much memory does the machine have? How much available memory does Task Manager report?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change the VM settings located in /framework/build.bat.

The default value of Xmx was 1024M and the error disappeared after I changed it to 784M.

Hope this helps.